# How to use msum to sum only positive numbers in DolphinDB

Tags: mysql, sql, database, dolphindb

I have a column numbers, positive or negative, such as the Val column in the table below;

```
msg = table(1..100 as id, rand(-100..100,100) as Val)
```

Now I want to calculate the moving summation for Val with the rolling window of length 10 ,but only calculate positive numbers in Val.Something like select msum( if(val>0), 10)  from msg.

Answer (score 0):

Use function `iif` to convert all negative numbers to zero and then use `msum` to calculate rolling sum.

```
msum(iif(val > 0, val, 0), 10)
```